# Reference about equivalent form of the Riemann hypothesis

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, riemann-hypothesis

I saw a statement about the Riemann hypothesis in Wikipedia, stating the following:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^{s}}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}$ holds for $Re(s)>\frac{1}{2}$ is equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis.

I tried to find a reference about it but I can't find it. May anyone provide a reference to the statement(with a proof) to it?

Comment: There are many references for statements  which are equivalent to RH. Did you already start searching yourself?

Comment: I tried to use keywords like "Riemann hypothesis", "Dirichlet series" but did not find anything about the proof of the statement. I guess I am looking for a book which proves it.

Comment: Basically it is equivalent to the fact that the Merten's function $M(x) := \sum_{n\leq x}\mu(n)$ is $O(x^{1/2+\varepsilon})$, which is equivalent to RH by elementary facts about Dirichlet series.

Comment: Thanks. I will look into those.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The paper [Riemann hypothesis equivalences, Robin
inequality, Lagarias criterion, and Riemann hypothesis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.08273.pdf) lists $36$ equivalent statements to RH, with references to complete proofs. We have
the following statement on page $8$:

**Equivalence 8:** RH is equivalent to the fact that the following series converges for $ℜ(s) > \frac{1}{2}$, see [48]:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s}=\frac{1}{\zeta(s)}.
$$
And $[48]$ is the book by Titchmarsh, The theory of the Riemann zeta function,second ed., Clarendon press. Oxford University press, New York, 1986.

There are some more posts at MO and MSE, e.g. [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39944/collection-of-equivalent-forms-of-riemann-hypothesis), where it is also referenced.